# How does SQLDatabase Chain work internally? (Langchain)

Tags: nlp, langchain

[Langchain Doc](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/sql_database)

I want to understand underlying implementation. I know it uses NLP. But how it is determining whether requested thing is table or column. Maybe they are using spacy but customised a bit to understand database terms.

What does it store in memory? Obviously they are not storing whole database. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76854677/12429704) answer,i got to know they are storing DDL of Database.  
But huge database will probably have large ddl. Won't that create issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation for SQLDatabaseChain

```
 https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/experimental/langchain_experimental/sql/base.py
```

Regarding your queries

What does it store in memory? Obviously they are not storing whole database.

**Answer :** Yes SQLDatabaseChain does not store entire database, it works based on metadata

From this answer,i got to know they are storing DDL of Database.
But huge database will mostly have large ddl. Won't that create issue?

**Answer :** Metadata mostly includes table names, column names, primary and foreign keys, all these information together sums up to  very small compared to DDL.

Comment: But quoting from [discussion](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/3730), it does "load up the DDL of the database into the context of the current session. [...] so [...] if the database has a large DDL [...] that [can] also create an issue".

Comment: Are you sure it loads metadata,not ddl? WHat is the difference between metadata and ddl ? I thought DDL is subset of metadata. Metadata may contain information about database too.

Comment: Metadata is data about data, providing details like structure and constraints of database elements. DDL is a subset of SQL used to define and modify the structure of a database, such as creating or altering tables

Answer (score 0):

> But how it is determining whether requested thing is table or column.

if you give this query "How many users are there in my database" to the chatgpt, it will assume that there is a `Users` table and it will search through `User` table. If you have User table, chatgpt will give you the correct answer. but if you ask this "How many different zip codes are there in shipping addresses". Maybe your table name is `Address` but chatgpt will assume that there is a `Shipping Address` table but it does not exist. so you will get an error something like "no column exist". you have to write code to handle this error. maybe you sent this error message to `chatgpt` and it will try again with a different approach.

You have to be more informative. chatgpt has to know what tables exist or not. You should send the available tables to the chatgpt